# Forced Air Unit will not go off

Tags: switch, central-air

My forced air unit never goes off.  It comes on intermittingly all day and night. I have a FAU switch in my breaker box and I have turned it off, but the forced air unit still runs day and night.  I have called out hvac repairmen to turn this off and they have disconnected a wire at the thermostat which did not make the fau stop running day and night.  One hvac repairman told me this was the design from the manufacturer and is a dip switch on the control board and cannot be changed.  I have contacted the hvac manufacturer customer service and their answer was “the hvac repairmen can get direction from the distributor is they need assistance on fixing issues”.  My conclusion is that the forced air unit is getting power from somewhere other than the fau switch to run intermittingly all day and night and the only other place it could be is attached to the main breaker switch.  I have tested my assumption and turned off all the switches  in the breaker box and the fau still runs.  When I turn off the main switch, no fau running.  What is your opinion/suggestion?  Can I get an electrician to move the fau power source to the fau switch and not the main breaker switch,  This way I can at least turn the fau switch off at night.

Comment: Is this a new or old problem?

Comment: Possible someone made a mistake and labelled the wrong breaker.  Usually there might be another switch/disconnect to turn off the FAU without the breaker.

Comment: Can you post photos of your breaker box please?

Comment: I have mine set to run 24/7, it helps greatly in keeping the temperature even and the air filtered.

Comment: "My forced air unit never goes off. It comes on intermittingly all day and night."  These 2 sentences mean different things.